# ASP.NET execute long running method in the background

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, methods

What I'm trying to accomplish: I want to call a long running business logic method from the code behind of an asp.net page (on a button click from the user) and have the process run asynchronously. The process has some business objects as parameters. Once the process kicks off the user should be displayed a screen indicating that they will be emailed the results; the important thing here is that the user not have to wait for the process to complete. What is the best way to do this? The process already exists and works in my project but the page just hangs while it runs.

Originally I thought about moving the method to a web service. Because it would require an extensive list of parameters I was going keep the signature the same and pass the web service business objects but I'm getting namespace errors. Specifically "Argument type MyBusinessLogic.MyObject is not assignable to parameter type MyWebService.MyObject" even though my web site and the web service are referencing the same DLL. I get why that is happening but I need a way around it.

The actual implementation of the solution is not terribly critical. It would be awesome if there was some way to run a method call asynchronously in ASP.NET that I'm not aware of. If not is sending and XML parameter list and parsing it into the business objects my only option for the Web Service?

Comment: Why not just start up a new thread to run the process, and return the response to redirect the user to the information page? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Threading like that is not encouraged in ASP.Net. The correct procedure is to use the Asynchronous ASP.Net page methods. More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what I ended up doing is close to Jeremy's method.

I found this site: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx which explains how to call a method asynchronously. To sum it up: If you define a proxy and call ProxyMethod.BeginInvoke(null,null) then the method will be run with no callback i.e. fire and forget. That was all I really wanted so it's what I'm going with. I don't know if it was necessary but I took the method itself and moved it from my codebehind into the business logic and made it a static method. So by code looks like this:

```
private delegate void AsyncReportGen(ReportParameterObject rpo);
protected void GenerateReport()
{
    //other code
    AsyncReportGen reportGen = ReportGenClass.GenerateReportStaticMethod;
    reportGen.BeginInvoke(rdo, null, null);
}
```

The GenerateReport method is called by a button click event. The GenerateReportStaticMethod fires off an email with the report attached when it is complete. The method called by BeginInvoke runs in it's own thread so the page can finish loading and show the user a message that they will receive an email. The user can then continue using the site or close their browser.

Comment: Sounds great. Glad to see you've got it sorted.

Comment: Yep for now. This process shouldn't be used often so I don't see an issue with multiple threads of it overloading the server. I guess we will see. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, so what I did is i moved the processing call to Pre_Render method and while it processes it calls (create) js function in the front end to update the progress.

```
Response.Write("fnUpdate('Processing 1 to 30 files')");
Response.Flush();
```

I need to change my processing logic so that it uses delegate to update the progress.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
Don't forget to increase the Script.Timeout

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 3600;
```

Comment: Once the processing is kicked off I don't care what happens to it. All I want is the page to start the process and then tell the user they will get an email so the user can continue on about their day. I don't need any sort of status update or anything. But thanks for the help.

Comment: In that case I would do a queue-ing system. So the page will just add the task in the queue and have a scheduler that will process the queue

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you using Async ASP.net pages.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I need. If I do this the page can't finish loading until the async task is complete correct? Once the task is fired off I don't care about it anymore. I can forget it's even running.

Comment: Overkill but possibly use some messaging service to tell another executable to kick up a thread and execute the task. Doing so you will not be added threads to the IIS worker processes. If you read that article it will explain the IIS worker process paradigm.

Comment: Also have a look at the Task Parallel Library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: I think I'm going to go with using a page delegate and calling the method using delegate.BeginInvoke(null,null). That accomplishes what I want and this feature shouldn't be used too often so I don't see thread issues. Is there some reason that I should not do this? I'm considering building into it something that will not let it start the method if there are fewer than X threads available but I don't know what X should be. I found this method here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx

Comment: Let us know how you go. Answer your own question if you have to :D